# Using ModifyStyle with WS_THICKFRAME on a CPropertySheet/CDialog

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

I have a CPropertySheet.

When I use

```
ModifyStyle(DS_MODALFRAME, WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);
```

inside an OnCreate handler everything is fine. The created window behaves as expected and is resizable.

When I use the same code, just a tick later in CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog than this code has only the effect that the correct frame is shown, also the cursor changes when I drag over the window border. But there is no resize feature.

Same happens for a CDialog when uses in OnInitDialog. Seams that some flags can't be changed after a window is created.

Is there more information about this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the [`nFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xhz2t1c.aspx) parameter to `SWP_FRAMECHANGED` and maybe also `SWP_DRAWFRAME` in your call to [`ModifyStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xhz2t1c.aspx). This way it will call [`SetWindowPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) internally, which will apply the new style. You also need to remove WS_SYSMENU instead of DS_MODALFRAME.

Example:

```
ModifyStyle(WS_SYSMENU, WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but: NO! This doesn't work! I just tested it. with a simple CDialog. In OnInitDialog I placed your code incl. SWP_DRAWFRAME. The effect is as described. The cursor form changes. Resizing does not happen.

Comment: Maybe you need to examine and modify or reset some ex styles (added by CDialog::OnInit) as well, using ModifyStyleEx.

Comment: No again. I cleared all flags with this code: ModifyStyle(DS_MODALFRAME, WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, SWP_FRAMECHANGED); ModifyStyleEx(0xFFFFFFFF, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
Your way doesn't work.

Comment: In fact in my case only WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE was set. And this has no influence on resizing.

Comment: I confirm what you see. The solution is to remove WS_SYSMENU instead of DS_MODALFRAME, like this: ModifyStyle(WS_SYSMENU, WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, SWP_FRAMECHANGED); (Answer edited)

Comment: I agree. This works, but sadly this is a real bad choice for me, because the icon gets lost and the complete system menu. I understand that the settings for the system menu or only used upon creation of the window. So it seams to me that it is a bad choice to modify this flags after window creation...